# Is there a TypeScript type for HTML class attributes?

Tags: css, typescript, svelte

Is there a TypeScript type for an HTML class attribute? I'm having difficulty searching for this because TypesScript itself has classes and this doesn't seem to be a common question.

To clarify, what I mean is, is there a type, example:

```
let anHTMLClass: HTMLClass = "foo-class";
```

that represents an HTML class (yes, I know it is technically a string type)

```
<div class={ anHTMLClass }></div>
```

The closest thing I can find is `svelte.JSX.HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>["class"]` (this is for Svelte, and unfortunately, I'm not getting the IntelliSense I'm after, it just ultimately evaluates to a string)

The reason why I'm looking for this is because Tailwind CSS has its amazing Intellisense when I'm choosing classes for my elements - but if I'm typing the class out as a `string` type and assigning it to a variable, I don't get this Intellisense. I'm hoping such a class exists and Intellisense would recognize the type.

Comment: A CSS class is always a `string`

Comment: You could create your own custom type: `type CSSClass = string;`

Comment: There's no such thing as a CSS class. CSS has class selectors which reference HTML classes. It looks like you are either asking about "An HTML class name" or "A valid value for an HTML class attribute" (which in React JSX is accessed via the `className` prop, not the `class` prop). I'm really not sure which.

Comment: @Samathingamajig in a structurally typed language that's pretty pointless though

Comment: I know I can create that type. I do actually think it's useful @jonrsharpe just as a form of self documentation, but why I really want this is for Intellisense...

Comment: Thanks @Quentin for the clarification, edited the post accordingly. Yes, I'm aware React JSX uses className. The point of this question is really for TailwindCSS, and I'm using it with Svelte (which just uses 'class').

Comment: I mean just aliasing a type is pointless. Tailwind presumably does it with a large [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) union.

Comment: We cannot use typescript in HTML. But we can use JSX in React, Solid.js or something else. Actually, the class's type is just string, but it also has alias. For example, I am using Solid.js. When I hover the `class` attr in `a` tag, it show `JSX.HTMLAttributes<T>.class?: string | undefined`, Here the `class`'s type is `JSX.HTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>.class`.

Comment: @PeterlitsZo Thanks for that. Well, the closest I could  get to it now thanks to your discovery is `svelte.JSX.HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>["class"]` (for a button), but I don't get the much sought-after intellisense I'm looking for, haha... After all that, when I hover over my `let defaultClass: svelte.JSX.HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>["class"]`, VSCode just tells me it's a string T_T

Comment: @Dois You are welcome. But I do not think use this long type is a good idea. What do you want to do. I can post an answer to help other people.

Comment: Basically, the entire point of this is that I want to get IntelliSense for TailwindCSS to work for strings that I will use as HTML Classes. Currently, the only way for it to work is when I'm editing a class directly in an HTML element's `class="..."`

I should really have just went to checkout Tailwind issues:
https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/7553

Comment: IntelliSence? Do you mean that the autofill of the tailwind CSS in your IDE or Editor? If it is, then it is the question of the editor plugin but not tailwind CSS. tailwind CSS works well, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is a copy of my comment. It is helpful for question-asker, so I think it can also help the other people.

1. HTML do not have type.
2. But JSX (or TSX) can have type.
3. The class (in React, we use className) is always `string | undefined`.
4. But it can also has a long name. For example, in Solid.js, which is also using JSX, the type of the attr `class` in tag `a` is: `JSX.HTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>.class`.

I do not think using this long name is a good idea. If you want to define a component, you can choose the short one - `string | undefined`.

But sometime it is a good idea. For example, if you want to define another anchor component, which is based on the basic `a` element, you can:

```
// Solid.js

interface AProps extends JSX.HTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement> {
  badname: string;
}

const A: Component<AProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <a {...props}>{badname}</a>
  );
}
```

Now you can use `A` just as the basic `a` with attr `badname`. Cool :)